# I can't make my pic appear on website

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying make "home-bg.jpg" appear on website but it doesn't appear. posted my codes below. need your help.

```
<header class="intro-header" style="<%= asset_path "home-bg.jpg" %>">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="site-heading">
                        <h1>Clean Blog</h1>
                        <hr class="small">
                        <span class="subheading">A Clean Blog Theme by Start Bootstrap</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Are you trying to set a background-image through style attribute? Try this.
`<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'home-bg.jpg' %>)">`

Comment: worked! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked. Can I post it as answer?

Comment: @Vishal You should post it as an answer. There is no need to ask OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'home-bg.jpg' %>)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a css file and set the background from there. Let's say you want to use it on your header you use.

```
.header {
background-image: url("home-bg.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to create an external stylesheet file to accomplish what are you trying to do.

You can write the following code to set **home-bg.jpg** as the background of `div`:

```
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'home-bg.jpg' %>)">
```